# MSDN OneNote Api: Navigate to never before opened page without opening a OneNote Application Window

Tags: c#, xml, api, window, onenote

My goal is to be able to use C# to programmatically open any *.one* section file and get all of the section's page ids. In a simple case (one where I have created and recently used the section), this can done with the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote;
class Program
{
    public static void ProcessOnenoteFile()
    {
        Application onenoteApp = new Application();
        string filepath = @"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\OneNote Notebooks\My Notebook\testsection.one";
        string sectionId;
        onenoteApp.OpenHierarchy(filepath, null, out sectionId);
        string hierarchy;
        onenoteApp.GetHierarchy(sectionId, HierarchyScope.hsPages, out hierarchy);
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\hierarchy.txt", hierarchy);
    }
}
```

From here I can parse the xml to find all the pageIds and I am good to go.

The problem, however, is that I want to do this with files I am getting from somebody else and have never opened before. When I run the same code on those files, I cannot find any pageIds in the hierarchy, and therefore, I cannot process any pages. A fix that seems to work is to use the navigateTo method to open the section file in OneNote before trying to get the hierarchy.

```
 ...
 string sectionId;
 onenoteApp.OpenHierarchy(filepath, null, out sectionId);
 onenoteApp.NavigateTo(sectionId);
 string hierarchy
 ...
```

This, however, is quite annoying as I need to open the OneNote application. Since I have many .one section files to process it would be a lot of random information flashing across the screen which is not necessary and might confuse the end users of my program. Is there a way I can achieve the same result of adding pageIds to the hierarchy without needing to open the OneNote Application? At the very least, is there a way I can hide the application?

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that using the Publish command also updates the hierarchy with pageIds, however, this solution is still not ideal as it requires me to make anotehr file.

Also, looking more closely at the xml export, I saw that there is a an attribute called "areAllPagesAvailable" which is set to false for me on all the files I have yet to open in OneNote.

Answer (score 1):

WooHoo! After a couple hours of just playing around and Google Searching the different methods, I have found what I am after.

Solution: SyncHierarchy(sectionId);

```
...
        string sectionId;
        onenoteApp.OpenHierarchy(onenoteFile, null, out sectionId, CreateFileType.cftSection);

        onenoteApp.SyncHierarchy(sectionId);

        string hierarchy;
        onenoteApp.GetHierarchy(sectionId, HierarchyScope.hsPages, out hierarchy);
...
```